# Foreign key not created with Hibernate Spring integrated code

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I am using org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.LocalSessionFactoryBean and have the following classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ORDERS")
public class Order implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private long id;
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn
    private Item item;
    ...
    }
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ITEM")
public class Item implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private long id;
private String img;
private long price;
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn
private ItemCategory category;
private String description;
...
}
```

But when the server comes up, for the ORDERS table there is no Foreign Key created:

```
 mysql> desc ORDERS;
    +------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | id         | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | item       | tinyblob     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | placedDate | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | quantity   | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | status     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    +------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

What could be wrong? Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This got resolved by moving the @OneToOne over the getter method.

There should be punishment for impatience but can anyone tell me why it did not work when the annotation was on the attribute itself?

Thanks